# Como imprimir una cadena de texto con pausas entre cada letra impresa en python 3.4?

Tags: python

Supongamos que tengo
*cadena= "aun me parece gracioso el chavo"*
deseo que el resultado sea 
*aun me parece gracioso el chavo*
pero que tras cada letra se haga una pequena pausa

pense en el codigo

```
for letra in cadena:
   print(letra, end="")
   time.sleep(0.3)
```

pero el resultado es

> a
>
> u
>
> n
>
> m
>
> e
>
> p
>
> a
>
> r
>
> e
>
> c
>
> e
>
> g
>
> r
>
> a
>
> c
>
> i
>
> o
>
> s
>
> o
>
> e
>
> l
>
> c
>
> h
>
> a
>
> v
>
> o

Como puedo hacer que se imprima en la misma linea con pausas de tiempo tras cada letra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta forma puede ayudar.

```
from time import sleep
import sys

text = "aun me parece gracioso el chavo"
for c in text:
    print(c, end='')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(0.5)
```

[demo](https://repl.it/DoLJ)

Comment: Funciono, me ayudo bastante, Muchas gracias =)

Answer (score 0):

Sin necesidad de usar el módulo `sys`

```
from time import sleep

text = "aun me parece gracioso el chavo"
for i in range(len(text)):
    print(text[0:i], end="\r")
    sleep(0.5)
print(text, end="\r")
```

A destacar el uso de `\r` en la función `print`. `\r` lleva el print al principio de la misma línea.

Comment: Buena alternativa sin tirar de sys, funciona perfectamente siempre que el string sea inferior al largo máximo de una linea en la terminal, si el estring necesita más de una linea de terminal para imprimirse no responde como deberia por el algoritmo que usa (uso del retorno de carro)

Comment: Es cierto, cuando hay saltos de linea no logra el objetivo. De todas maneras muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import time

def lxl(texto, velocidad):
    for caracter in texto:
        print(caracter, end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(velocidad)

lxl("Hola Mundo",0.5)
```

Comment: Hola Manuel, bienvenido y gracias por tu colaboración, las respuestas que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, te sugiero que edites la tuya, y expliques de que forma resuelve el problema planteado, así evitarás que sea cerrada y/o recibir votos negativos.

Comment: @MarcePuente una respuesta no se puede cerrar :)

Comment: @padaleiana, so haber puesto "eliminada?...

Comment: @MarcePuente una respuesta de baja calidad solo se elimina si tiene _graves problemas de formato o contenido_ (tal como indica el tipo de reporte). A esta solo le falta una edición con explicación del código.

Comment: @padaleiana, estas totalmente equivocada :)

Comment: @MarcePuente Nope :)

Comment: @padaleiana, prueba comentar la respuesta (indicando un error en la misma) de un moderador poco receptivo, y verás como de golpe, se te cierran cinco respuestas en dos semanas!!