# Como puede evitar generar saltos de linea mientras uso print en python3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo la siguiente función

```
 def reproducir(texto):
    pygame.mixer.music.load(TECLADO) 

    for letra in str(texto):
       pygame.mixer.music.play()
       print(letra, end="")
       time.sleep(0.05)
       sys.stdout.flush()

 pygame.mixer.music.stop()
```

como pueden ver la función imprime letra por letra el texto con un sonido de fondo.

Si pulso enter mientras se imprimen las letras genera salto de linea y distorsiona el msj.

Si presiona cualquier otra letra se imprime en pantalla y me distorsiona el msj.

¿Cómo puedo evitar que esto ocurra?

Comment: Quizá probar con `print(letra, end="", flush=True)` o revisar mi anterior respuesta, quizá le ayude http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25901/como-imprimir-una-cadena-de-texto-con-pausas-entre-cada-letra-impresa-en-python/25902#25902

Comment: no funciona del todo porque aun puedo ingresar letras a traves del teclado y se cuelan entre las letras que se van imprimiendo.

Comment: seria mas bien como evitar que se puedo usar el teclado mientras se van imprimiendo las letras. Es lo que se me ocurre, no se si tienes una idea mejor. Muchas gracias de todas formas.

Answer (score 1):

He conseguido utilizar curses para conseguir lo que buscaba, sin embargo me parece que debe haber otra forma más sencilla.

En cuanto a `sys.stdout.flush()` no me sirvio como esperaba ya que al final cuando ingresaba un valor se guardaban las teclas que se pulsadas anteriormente.

Consegui `sys.stdin.flush()` y no me dio los resultados esperados, pero me funcionó lo siguiente:

```
termios.tcflush(sys.stdin, termios.TCIOFLUSH)
```